# Why do I get 'error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.6 cannot open shared object file' even after I run ldconfig?

Tags: ubuntu, symlink

The symlink libssl.so.6 shows up in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, and I ran `ldconfig` but I still get this error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is it a permissions issue or the link is not properly defined?

Update after running ldd on the binary:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff1efe2000)
    libssl.so.6 => not found
    libcrypto.so.6 => not found
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007feb2a3c4000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007feb2a1bb000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007feb29f82000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007feb29d65000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007feb29b60000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007feb297a1000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007feb2b159000)
```

Comment: Run the `ldd` command on the binary that is showing this error and update your question with the output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the `ldd` command it looks like the binary is looking in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and not `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` where you found the symlink.

Try running these and see if you still get the same error:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.6
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.6
```

Comment: I ran similar 'sudo ln' commands without understanding what's going on, but things work fine now!

Comment: @blueseal, `ln -s` creates a `symlink` from the `libssl.so.1.0.0` binary to `libssl.so.6` filename in the `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` directory. `sudo` permissions are needed as `/lib` is a root directory.

Comment: I can't upvote, but I really appreciate your effort for the clarification!

Comment: @blueseal, don't worry. Glad to help!

Comment: I try ln not works, but I move these to the lib dir works