# need to have libcrypto++.so.6 on my jessie

Tags: debian, software-installation, libraries

I need `libcrypto++.so.6` on my jessie for some application to be ran. This is what I have in `/usr/lib/`:

```
root@lab-185:~# ls /usr/lib/ | grep libcrypto
libcrypto++.a
libcryptopp.a
libcryptopp.so
libcryptopp.so.9
libcrypto++.so
libcrypto.so.1.0.0
libcrypto++.so.9
libcrypto++.so.9.0.0
```

And the `aptitude` shows:

```
root@lab-185:~# aptitude search libcrypto
i   libcrypto++-dev                                                    - General purpose cryptographic library - C++ development                      
i   libcrypto++-doc                                                    - General purpose cryptographic library - documentation                        
i   libcrypto++-utils                                                  - General purpose cryptographic library - utilities and data files             
i A libcrypto++9                                                       - General purpose cryptographic library - shared library                       
i   libcrypto++9-dbg                                                   - General purpose cryptographic library - debug symbols                        
i   libcrypto1.0.0-udeb                                                - Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - libcrypto udeb
```

This is `strace` of my app:

```
root@lab-185:~# strace ./app  2>&1 | grep libcrypto
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/libcrypto++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libcrypto++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
writev(2, [{"./app", 15}, {": ", 2}, {"error while loading shared libra"..., 36}, {": ", 2}, {"libcrypto++.so.6", 16}, {": ", 2}, {"cannot open shared object file", 30}, {": ", 2}, {"No such file or directory", 25}, {"\n", 1}], 10./app: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I have it on my system?

**EDIT 1:**

Command `ldd` returns:

```
root@lab-185:~# ldd app
./app: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by ./app)
./app: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by ./app)
./app: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./app)
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcb69e4000)
    libnetsnmp.so.30 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmp.so.30 (0x00007f5661c32000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5661a15000)
    liblog4cxx.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblog4cxx.so.10 (0x00007f566162c000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f5661424000)
    libxerces-c-3.1.so => /usr/lib/libxerces-c-3.1.so (0x00007f5660e1c000)
    libxqilla.so.6 => /usr/lib/libxqilla.so.6 (0x00007f56605aa000)
    libcrypto++.so.6 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f566029f000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f565ff9e000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f565fd88000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f565f9df000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f565f5e4000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f566245c000)
    libapr-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapr-1.so.0 (0x00007f565f3af000)
    libaprutil-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaprutil-1.so.0 (0x00007f565f186000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f565ef6e000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f565ed6a000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f565eb65000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f565e92e000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f565e705000)
```

**EDIT 2:**

I have tried [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186627/why-do-i-get-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libssl-so-6-cannot-open-shar?answertab=oldest#tab-top); it didn't work.

```
ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.6
ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.6
ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto++.so.6
```

**EDIT 3:**

I have `libstdc++6` already:

```
root@lab-185:~# aptitude search libstdc++
p   libstdc++-4.8-dev                                                  - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)                              
i A libstdc++-4.9-dev                                                  - GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)                              
v   libstdc++-dev                                                      -                                                                              
p   libstdc++5                                                         - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3                                              
i   libstdc++6                                                         - GNU Standard C++ Library v3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get 'error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.6 cannot open shared object file' even after I run ldconfig?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186627/why-do-i-get-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libssl-so-6-cannot-open-shar)

Comment: @GraysonKent, I have tried answer of that question; didn't work for me.

Comment: From your posted error messages, it looks like you are also missing libstdc++6. Can you try `sudo apt-get install libstdc++6` ?

Comment: @GraysonKent, I have it already. Review my edits on the question please.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is to download the current Stretch binary, which will work fine in Jessie:

```
wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libc/libcrypto++/libcrypto++6_5.6.4-7_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libcrypto++6_5.6.4-7_amd64.deb
```

You’ll need to keep an eye out for possible updates (subscribe to the [package tracker](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/libcrypto++) using the big blue “Subscribe” button in the top-right-hand corner).

Given the errors produced by `ldd`, I doubt this will be sufficient to run your application: you’d need a newer version of `libstdc++6` too. That’s harder to upgrade in place, you’d be better off upgrading to Debian 9.